# Prove $n^k < a^n$

Tags: inequality

I have the following Number theory question.

Prove $n^k < a^n$ for all $n$ greater than some large integer. 
$n, k$, and $a$ are all integers. $a$, and $k$ are constants.

Appreciate proof for the above.

Comment: If $a=1$ it will be hard because it is false.  Please state the question correctly.  What are the ranges of the variables?

Comment: But of trouble if $a \le 0$.  $a$ being integer isn't really relevant so much as $a > 1$ which is *very* relevant yet utterly unstated.

Comment: Also given, $a > 1$

Answer (score 0):

First, assume $a > 1$, $k > 0$, then choose $n > k$, and use the fact that $n > \dfrac{k\ln n}{\ln a}$ for all $n \ge N_0 > 1$, and $N_0 > k$, and this is true since $\dfrac{n}{\ln n} \to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$, and the answer follows.